# Defining two api end points with same generic class view Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django. I was trying to use django generic views, class based.

How do I implement following situation, I have two api end points login/ and logout/ and the same view class handles it ?

```
# Login and logout
class SignInActivity(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    request = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(Q(username=self.request.data["username"])
                               & Q(userpassword=self.request.data["userpassword"]))

    def update(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        query_set = self.get_queryset()

        if bool(query_set):
            query_set.update_or_create(username=self.request.data["username"],
                                   userpassword=self.request.data["userpassword"],
                                   defaults={
                                        "lastlogin": timezone.now()
                                    })
            return Response(data={"message": "User logged in successfully.", "response_code": 222}, status=201)
        else:
            return Response(data={"message": "User not found.", "response_code": 444}, status=201)
```

And my urls.py is

```
path('login/', SignInActivity.as_view())
```

This implementation hadles login/ with this class, PUT method. Now can I use  same class with another  method to handle logout/  PUT method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default **`generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView`** provides 3 HTTP methods, which are `GET`,`PUT`,`PATCH`. You could override any of the following methods to `logout` procedure.

```
class SignInActivity(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    request = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(Q(username=self.request.data["username"])
                                   & Q(userpassword=self.request.data["userpassword"]))

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data="HTTP PUT method")

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(data="HTTP PATCH method")

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # your log-out logic
        return Response(data="HTTP GET method")
```

I think you can use **`retrieve()`** method to do logout procedure, because, there is no need of sending additional payloads to the end-point, I assume

Comment: But, otherwise it is not possible then I suppose, that is if I don't override the above methods. So for a class based views, I have to create  a new class every time I am defining a new end point, if they are on same method that is PUT in my case.

Comment: oops... I don't understand your concern. Actually, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't point same end-points to **same methods(`PUT`)** of same ViewClass

Comment: Exactly my concern. Point different PUT method of same class by some way of routing and specifying the method name. Anyways, found a solution with inheritance.

Comment: Add that solution to your question, that may help others

Comment: Done, added an answer for my solution.

Comment: In the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to points two end points to same method function (POST  or PUT) of the same view class.

One of the  solution  could be to use inheritance, where  there could be a base class and login and logout endpoint classes inheriting from this class, and later implement respective method functions inside the  child classes.

So basically, the two end points will still use functions of different  class, with common properties inherited.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SignInActivity(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
```

should be

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
class SignInActivity(APIView):
```

Urls.py

```
path('login/', SignInActivity.as_view()),
path('logout/', SignInActivity.as_view())
```

This should be doing the fact as when the request is recieved our domain.com/logout/ it would forward it to the SignInActivity View as well as when request over domain.com/login/ is received!